# Find values greater than the mean of each column of data in a matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, matrix

I have a matrix including 5 columns(months) and 4 rows(years) indicating monthly precipitation. How to find values greater than the average of each column (month). The values of each column should be compared with the average data of each column and if it is greater print 1 instead of that value or else print 0 so we have a matrix with the same rows and columns with 0 or 1 value.

here is random data.

`w= randi([1 12], 4,5)`

w =

```
 1    12     1     8     9
 9     3    11     3    10
 8     2     8    12     1
 2     1     7     8    10
```

for example

```
result=
     0     1     0     1     1
     1     0     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: Why is `result(1,1)`  equal to `0` when that entry is greater than the mean of its column? Your example result does not seem to match your description, which would correspond to `result = w > mean(w, 1);`

Comment: Dear Luis, it is just an example not the real result. e.g. the average of the first column is  7.33 so the value 10 which is less than 7.33 will be 0. i know the result is not match, i just mentioned that to better understanding.

Comment: I edited that, so I think it so easy to understand what I mean and need. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = randi([1 5],4,6);
[rows, columns] = size (A);
for i = 1:columns
  for j =1:rows
   if  A(j,i) >= mean(A(:,i));
    P(j,i) = 1;
   else P(j,i)=0;
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should compute `m = mean(A)` only once, then recall `m(i)` in the comparison.

Comment: the answer works ok. The input matrix is small. +1 to Sorena.

Answer (score 3):

You only need

```
result = w > mean(w, 1);
```

which makes use of [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/). Note that the result is of type `logical`; if necessary you can convert to `double`.

Comment: thanks. but it is not something I am looking for. the average of each columns should be calculated then the values of each columns compare with the corresponding average.

Comment: @Sorena The average of each column is computed with `mean(w, 1)`. Then, `w > mean(w, 1)` compares each entry with the average of its column

Comment: yes. but it doesn't work for me. Error using  > 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: That must be some other problem with your code. See [here](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/XMFWIVrBUAEIDI0UwBSYtACTllwKEBpMGoOlDZHYBlB5iGojBBtmFlQe2WRzJFUGsdZcRanFpTklQGeUK9gp5KYm5mmU6ygYav7/DwA)

Comment: @Sorena If you get that error running this line of code, then you must have a really old version of MATLAB. You will need to use `bsxfun` to do the comparison.